# How to sort plus minus string start from biggest minus?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, sorting

I want to sort array string of percent : `["-12.00%", "3.00%", "27.30%", "-8.37%"]`

```
var array: [String]?
array = ["-12.00%", "3.00%", "27.30%", "-8.37%"]
```

I try with convert string to double then sort it with :
`array.sorted(by: { Double($0.string ?? "") ?? 0.0 < Double($1.string ?? "") ?? 0.0 })` but failed

The result that I want after sort is `["-12.00%", "-8.37%", "3.00%", "27.30%"]`

How to sort with the result like I want, the biggest minus is on the lead until biggest plus is at the end?

Comment: It would be better to start with an array of doubles. That way you can just sort them. You can always present them as strings later.

Comment: What type is the objects in the array? If it's not a standard type, please post relevant parts of its implementation e.g. the `string` property and internal representation.

Comment: You should debug: `$0.string`, and `Double($0.string)` values. Then you might see what's wrong, and that's the conversion from String into "numbers". You could use a `NumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "%" symbol may be causing the problem. If it is always the last character then you could use `.dropLast()` to remove it.

Then the function `.sorted` returns a new array, it doesn't sort the array *in situ*.

Here is how these changes can be applied to your original attempt, assuming you start with an array of strings:

```swift
let array = ["-12.00%", "3.00%", "27.30%", "-8.37%"]
let sortedArray = array.sorted {
    (Double($0.dropLast()) ?? 0.0) < (Double($1.dropLast()) ?? 0.0)
}
print(sortedArray)
```

```
["-12.00%", "-8.37%", "3.00%", "27.30%"]
```

Comment: It's not "may". The `%` *is* causing the problem. `Double("1.2%")` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use a formatter to parse the string into numbers and then sort the numbers. It requires some extra work but it feels a bit safer than manually parsing the code

```
let format = Decimal.FormatStyle.Percent.percent.precision(.fractionLength(2)).locale(Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX"))
let array = ["-12.00%", "3.00%", "27.30%", "-8.37%"]
let sorted = array
    .compactMap {
        try? Decimal.ParseStrategy(format: format).parse($0)
    }
    .sorted()
    .map { $0.formatted(format) }
```

Comment: This not only offers more robust parsing, but also avoids repeatedly parsing the strings. For the sake of completeness, rather than reconstructing the “percent” strings, the OP might alternatively want to either just return the original strings (via tuples), or just return the array of numeric values. But the OP wasn’t very specific. Good answer (+1).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the following process:

1. first extract the num values from each % string, and then
2. removes the '%' character, and converts them to Double.
3. Then, it compares the numerical values considering the sign of the percentages to achieve the desired sorting order.

Code:

```
let percentages = ["-12.00%",  "3.00%", "27.30%", "-8.37%"]

let sortedPercentages = percentages.sorted { (str1, str2) -> Bool in

guard let value1 = Double(str1.dropLast().replacingOccurrences(of: "%", with: "")),
      let value2 = Double(str2.dropLast().replacingOccurrences(of: "%", with: "")) else {
    return false 
}


if value1 < 0 && value2 < 0 {
    return value1 > value2 
} else if value1 >= 0 && value2 >= 0 {
    return value1 < value2 
} else {
    return value1 < value2 // negative values then positive values
}
}
print(sortedPercentages)
```

Output: ["-12.00%", "-8.37%", "3.00%", "27.30%"]

Comment: thanks dropLast() is the answer I need.

Comment: array.sorted(by: { Double($0.string?.dropLast() ?? "") ?? 0.0 < Double($1.string?.dropLast() ?? "") ?? 0.0 })

Answer (score 0):

A few considerations:

1. Another alternative is to use `Double(_:format:)` with a *format* of `.percent`, rather than `Double(_:)`.

   So that might look like:

   ```swift
   let array = ["-12.00%", "3%", "27.30%", "-8.37%"]

   let results = array.sorted { string0, string1 in
       let value0 = try? Double(string0, format: .percent)
       let value1 = try? Double(string1, format: .percent)

       return (value0 ?? .infinity) < (value1 ?? .infinity)
   }
   ```

   As an aside, I would use [`infinity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/infinity), rather than `0`, for the `nil` coalescing operator’s default value, so that unparsable strings do not just randomly appear in between the negative and positive values. Or if you want to know about parsing issues, I might `guard let` the unwrapping of these values. But the idea is that defaulting to zero might lead to strange results.
2. Personally, I might avoid using the default value of `0` for the `nil` coalescing operator, and instead fall back to something more intuitive, such as a string comparison. This ensures that:

   - two non-percent strings will be compared as strings;
   - strings are sorted after the numeric values (but you can flip that around if you want; and
   - two strings will be sorted in a logical manner (e.g., “a” before “b”, etc.):

   Thus, perhaps:

   ```swift
   let results = array.sorted { string0, string1 in
       let value0 = try? Double(string0, format: .percent)
       let value1 = try? Double(string1, format: .percent)

       switch (value0, value1) {
       case (nil, nil): return string0 < string1
       case (_, nil):   return true
       case (nil, _):   return false
       default:         return value0! < value1!
       }
   }
   ```

   Admittedly, if sorting an array of percentage strings, this might be too much of an edge case to worry about, but FWIW.
3. I like to avoid doing too much inside the `sorted` closure (as it is called multiple times for each value in the array, which can be inefficient), so I like to first map the array of strings to an array of tuples (of original string and what I want to sort by), then sort on the numeric values (if I can), and then extract the original strings back out of the sorted tuples:

   ```swift
   let results = array
       .map { (string: $0, double: try? Double($0, format: .percent)) }
       .sorted { tuple0, tuple1 in
           let value0 = tuple0.double
           let value1 = tuple1.double

           switch (value0, value1) {
           case (nil, nil): return tuple0.string < tuple1.string 
           case (_, nil):   return true
           case (nil, _):   return false
           default:         return value0! < value1!
           }
       }
       .map { $0.string }
   ```

There are many other refinements and observations that I might suggest, but I do not want to distract us from the key observation, that if you want a `Double` representation of a percentage string, you can include the `format` parameter of `.percent`. There are other ways to achieve this, but this is just one example.